# 5000x5000 Grid of images for Python Tkinter Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making a action adventure sandbox video game. It's quite similar to the game "Terraria". Therefore it involves placing and destroying blocks. Right now, to destroy blocks, basically it just adds a rectangle the same color as the sky where you clicked. However, I don't want that. I don't want it so you can freely draw images in the ground with destroying blocks. I decided to change the world in the game to a grid of tiles, that are PhotoImages. I am having a lot of trouble with it.
Here is the code I am focusing on:

```
DirtImage = PhotoImage(file = '/home/tyty0427/Downloads/New Piskel(61).png')
GrassImage = PhotoImage(file = '/home/tyty0427/Downloads/New Piskel(62).png')
TilePlacement = (10, 5000)
for row in range(5000):
    c.create_image(TilePlacement, image=DirtImage, tags='Tile')
    TilePlacement += (20, 0)
```

And I don't even know where to even *start* for the columns in the grid! Any help please?

Comment: tkinter is a technology for GUI, you're going to have a hard time making a graphics heavy game with it. How about using something game specific, like pygame or (sic) gamemaker studio?

Comment: I don't want to do that because this game started development when I thought tkinter was MEANT for games. Unfortunatley it's not. But I would have to redo everything (And thats alot to redo) if I decided to change and use those.

Comment: the good thing about redoing is that things are always better the second time you make them...

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What kind of help do you need? What does "having a lot of trouble with it" mean?

Answer (score 1):

You should store your world in a structure that is easy to reference.  A numpy array might be handy.  This will be handy as a coordinate system, too, since you can map floats of the player's coordinates to integers to determine which tile they're on.

You could have integer values in the numpy array and then those integers could map to tiles.  This way, the behavior when interacting with a tile would be based on the value stored in the array.  Something like

```
tile_names = {0: 'empty', 1: 'dirt', 2: 'grass'}
tile_sprites = {0: PhotoImage(file = '/path/to/sky'),
                1: PhotoImage(file = '/home/tyty0427/Downloads/New Piskel(61).png'), 
                2: PhotoImage(file = '/home/tyty0427/Downloads/New Piskel(62).png')}
world = np.zeros((5000,5000))
```

You can use slices of the numpy array to limit the viewport to a small section of the world (eg if your window is 500x100 tiles):

```
x_offset = 4000
y_offset = 50
for x in range(100):
    for y in range(500):
        sprite = tile_sprites[world[y_offset:y_offset+y, x_offset:x_offset+x]]
        c.create_image((20*y, 20*x), image=tile_sprites[val], tags='Tile')
```

If you want to grab a section of the world, you could then do

```
world[y_0:y_0+h, x_0:x_0+w]
```

Comment: Okay but when i do the "world = np.zeros((5000,5000))" it says "module "numpy" has no attribute "zeros"" Help again please? XD

Comment: What code are you using?  Did you import numpy?  Could you link to it on github or pastebin or something?

Comment: I imported numpy, yes. I'm trying out the code you said to see how it works and stuff.

Comment: It shouldn't give you any trouble.  Here's what I'm doing when I use np.zeros: http://i.imgur.com/ZjMOOvL.png